# Matrix, Safecracker Registration - multiple channels for member fields

Tags: members, channel, member-details

I got Matrix to represent line item entries and Safecracker Registration so I can use Channels as member fields. I will be creating 2-3 member groups, for example:

- Member Group A: field 1, field 2, field 3
- Member Group B: field 1, field 2, field 3, field 4, field 5

Since fields 1-3 are the same between Member Group A and B, is there a way for me to put them together in a common Channel, then put fields 4-5 in another Channel -- and then somehow associate the various Channels to be used a member fields?

Splitting the Channels is simple enough. I'm just not sure how using Channels work with member fields, etc. I'm trying to prevent duplicating my efforts when it comes to defining these fields in the Channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to store all your fields in the same field group and assign that field group to each member channel. Then you show/hide what you need on the edit form using [**Publish Layouts**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/publish_page_layouts.html).

This will only cause issues if:

- You have a ton of fields in that field group because all fields will be loaded on the edit page and only the ones you select will be visible.
- You have required fields that aren't required across all channels using the fields. A required field will throw a validation error even if it's hidden. The editor then can never save the entry.

I asked a similar question here when we first launched the site to get the ball rolling:
[Shared field group?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/451/shared-field-group)

Comment: I could use SAEF to prevent #1 issue you raised, right? I don't think #2 will be an issue for me (maybe).

Comment: If you are using SafeCracker to build your edit forms in templates, then #1 isn't an issue if you manually add the fields you need to each form. Not sure if required fields will throw errors if they aren't present in the template. You'll need to test that. If there are errors, then remove the "required" setting on the field and do your validation with JS in the template.

Comment: You're most welcome. Is this your first EE project? Sounds like a challenging first project if it is. You're going to learn a ton. Keep posting questions and we'll get you through it.